# Не работает роут profile на FOS UserBundle

Tags: php, symfony2, symfony, sonata

Я использую `FOSUserBundle` с `SonataAdminUserBundle`. Но не получается открыть страницу по адресу `/profile`. Выдает ошибку:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Unable to generate a URL for the named route "sonata_user_profile_edit" as such route does not exist.") in SonataUserBundle:Profile:action.html.twig at line 27.

Вот мой *routing.yml*:

```
#app/config/routing.yml
app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation

main:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /
# FOSUserBundle's routing
fos_user_security:
  resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"

fos_user_profile:
  resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/profile.xml"
  prefix: /profile

fos_user_register:
  resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/registration.xml"
  prefix: /register

fos_user_resetting:
  resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/resetting.xml"
  prefix: /resetting

fos_user_change_password:
  resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/change_password.xml"
  prefix: /profile

# Admin's routing
sonata_user:
  resource: '@SonataUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/admin_security.xml'
  prefix: /admin

admin:
  resource: '@SonataAdminBundle/Resources/config/routing/sonata_admin.xml'
  prefix: /admin

_sonata_admin:
  resource: .
  type: sonata_admin
  prefix: /admin
```

Но `/profile/edit` работает как надо. Вопрос на подобие моего уже успели задать  [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32475287/display-profile-fos-userbundle-sonata-userbundle) и [здесь](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/issues/2307) но так и не решили.

Comment: А `/profile/` открывается?

Comment: уже решил проблемку . Точнее помогли . Надо писать роуты SonatUserBunde вместо FOSUserBunde. [Вот тут есть все](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/user/2-2/doc/reference/profile_edition.html) . Но все равно спасибо !

Comment: Напиши ответ на свой вопрос и отметь его как правильный или же просто удали его. По идее, если хотя бы один человек за вопрос проголосовал, значит есть интерес у народа, но мне кажется тут проголосовали люди, не сильные в теме, больше для поддержания самого ресурса. Вообще, игнорирование документации к хорошим вопросам относить нельзя, поэтому для меня немного обидно, что такой вопрос может быть востребован.

Comment: @MichaelSivolobov вы правы , хотел удалить но решил вдруг кому то окажется полезным ,  лучше учиться на чужих ошибках

Comment: Тогда следует оформить грамотный ответ. Но как по мне: вопрос захламляет топик.

Comment: следующий раз буду учесть . Есть идеи по улучшению вопроса